# Is there a reason the OZ governor contract can't see it's own function or is it the way I am calling it?

Tags: ethers.js, openzeppelin, dao, governance, timelock

So I am having an issue with a DAO.

I'm using https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance and https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController

```
function swapRoles(
        address formerCanceller1,
        address formerCanceller2,
        address formerCanceller3,
        address newCanceller1,
        address newCanceller2,
        address newCanceller3
    ) public onlyRole(TIMELOCK_ROLE) {
        revokeRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, formerCanceller1);
        revokeRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, formerCanceller2);
        revokeRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, formerCanceller3);
        grantRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, newCanceller1);
        grantRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, newCanceller2);
        grantRole(CANCELLER_ROLE, newCanceller3);
        lastAdjustedCancelerRole = block.timestamp;
    }
```

I added the above function to Gov, not timelock... pretty sure I understand that the cancel can happen in both and why but if you want to enlighten me, do kindly :)

I do not understand why this is failing:

```
it("propose a swap", async function () {
        const calldata = governor.interface.encodeFunctionData("swapRoles", [
            cancel1.address,
            cancel2.address,
            cancel3.address,
            newCanceller1.address,
            newCanceller2.address,
            newCanceller3.address,
          ]);
```

THIS WAY DOESN'T FIND IT:

```
            const functionSignature = "swapRoles(address,address,address,address,address,address)";
            const selector = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(functionSignature)).slice(0, 10);
            const addresses = [
            cancel1.address,
            cancel2.address,
            cancel3.address,
            newCanceller1.address,
            newCanceller2.address,
            newCanceller3.address,
            ];
            const encodedParams = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
            ["address", "address", "address", "address", "address", "address"],
            addresses
            );
            const calldata = selector + encodedParams.slice(2);
            const targets = [governor.address];
            const values = [0];
            const calldatas = [calldata];
            const description = "Swap canceller roles";
            // Delegate tokens if necessary
            await token.delegate(deployer.address); // Make sure the deployer has tokens and is a voter
            // Propose the role swap
           const proposeTx = await governor.propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
//   const receipt = await proposeTx.wait()
```

It has an interface and I've also tried this:

```
.interface.encodeFunctionData(
```

Here is the error they both return in hardhat:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function`
```

Is there a reason the governor contract can't see it's own function or is it the way I am calling it?